# plotly basic example shows no plot in jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I just tried to use plotly offline in a jupyter notebook (using jupyter lab).  The [docs](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#start-plotting-online) gives this example:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

plotly.offline.iplot({
    "data": [go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 3, 2, 1])],
    "layout": go.Layout(title="hello world")
})
```

I tried it and there is no chart displayed, either in Edge or Firefox.
An output cell is made in the notebook, but there is no chart.

It works if I use plotly.offline.plot rather than iplot.  It works if I use the traditional jupyter notebook rather than jupyter lab.

Any ideas why it does not display?

It's plotly version 2.7.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed Plotly JupyterLab extension? It will not work inline without it. You can get it here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/tree/master/packages/plotly-extension

or just install via terminal: `jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension`

Comment: Installed Node.js 10.16.0 using the windows installer, but when I executed the terminal command, I get the error "ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation...". Not sure how to make jupyter lab recognize/find what it needs.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough points to add the comment: The @jupyterlab/plotly-extension has been deprecated in favor of the plotly supported render extension, which is at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jupyterlab-plotly.

Install via:

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly
```

Comment: I confirm that it works