# JupyterLab build is suggested and successfully installed, but will not work. Why?

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm running JupyterLab from Anaconda, and installed a [JupyterLab plotly extension](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyterlab-plotly-extension) using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab-plotly-extension
```

Apparently, the installation was successful, but something is still wrong.
When launching JuyterLab, I'm getting this prompt:

[image]

Clicking `BUILD` gives me this:

[image]

And clicking `RELOAD` relods JupyterLab, BUT I'm getting this again:

[image]

And on and on it spins. Does anyone know why?

Clicking `CANCEL` does not help either because plotly won't produce any plots, only [blank spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264181/plotly-basic-example-shows-no-plot-in-jupyter-lab):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution:**

Deactivate firewall and run the following command in a windows command prompt:

```
jupyter lab build
```

---

**The details:**

This turned out to be a firewall problem, and I'm not sure why it would not be prompted as such in the JupyterLab interface. The following command in a windows command prompt returned the error message below:

**Command:**

```
jupyter lab build
```

**Output:**

> C:>jupyter labextension list JupyterLab v0.34.9 Known labextensions: 
>   app dir:
>   C:\Users*******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
>           @jupyterlab/plotly-extension v0.18.2 enabled  ok
>
> Build recommended, please run `jupyter lab build`:
>       @jupyterlab/plotly-extension needs to be included in build
>
> C:>jupyter lab build [LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 0.34.9 [LabBuildApp]
>   Building in
>   C:\Users*******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
>   [LabBuildApp] > node
>   C:\Users*******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js
>   install yarn install v1.9.4 info No lockfile found. [1/4] Resolving
>   packages... error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@jupyterlab%2fapplication: self signed
>   certificate in certificate chain". info If you think this is a bug,
>   please open a bug report with the information provided in
>   "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn-error.log".

What pointed me towards suspecting a firewall problem was this part:

> self signed certificate in certificate chain

Running the same command on less rigid fire-wall settings triggers this output (shortened):

> WARNING in d3-array   Multiple versions of d3-array found:
>       1.2.4 ./~/d3-scale/~/d3-array from ./~/d3-scale/~/d3-array\src\index.js
>       2.2.0 ./~/d3-array from ./~/d3-array\src\index.js
>
> Check how you can resolve duplicate packages:
>   https://github.com/darrenscerri/duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin#resolving-duplicate-packages-in-your-bundle
>
> Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>        1 asset
>       Entrypoint undefined = index.html
>       [KTNU] ./node_modules/html-loader!./templates/partial.html 567 bytes {0} [built]
>       [YuTi] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
>       [aS2v] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./templates/template.html
>   1.22 KiB {0} [built]
>       [yLpj] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
>           + 1 hidden module

And despite some warning messages, JupyterLab now produces plotly figures without any problems:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to solve the build error, other than disable firewall?